# Два вопроса - из одного анекдота

Tags: выбор-слов, падежи, суффиксы

Прочитала в приличной газете (тираж 14000 экз.) приличный анекдот:

— Я люблю тебя! Весь мир к твоим ногам положу. Отдам тебе всё, что у меня есть: сердце, разум, тело, звёзды, слова, стихи, песни, **душа**.
 — А что, **денюжек** совсем нет?

Возникло два вопроса:
 **1.** Как правильно — душ**А** или душ**У**?
 **2.** Возможно ли использование в этом контексте  "ден**Е**жка - ден**Ю**жка"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)  **Обобщающее слово "всё" и однородный ряд в форме В.п.:**

Отдам тебе **всё**, что у меня есть: сердце, разум, тело, звёзды, слова, стихи, песни, **душу.**

2) **Деньги, денежки, денюжки**

Деньги и (ласкат.) денежки — существительное мн. числа.  Денежек дать? Плакали мои д. Пропали, не вернёшь.  Денежки счёт любят (Погов.).

Также: **Денежка** — мелкая медная монета в 1/2 копейки, чеканившаяся в России в 1849—1866 годах.

**Денюжки** —  ненормированная форма, **то же, что денежки.** Используется в разговорной речи, обычно с **дополнительным ласкательным** значением,  а также может применяться в **публицистике для выражения иронии.** В приведенном тексте слово  "денюжек" сочетает ласкательное и ироническое значение.

**Примеры:**

Отольются они тебе, эти **денюжки**, вспомнишь ты их не раз. [Василий Шукшин. Микроскоп (1969)]. И **денюжки** не какие-нибудь, а пять миллиардов зеленых рублей, выделенных сердобольным МВФ на возрождение угасающей России. [Елизавета Козырева. Дамская охота (2001)]

Comment: посмотрите,пожалуйста, нашего-Вашего пролетария.

Answer (score 0):

1. И в приличной газете бывают опечатки. После двоеточия (оно только стоит после ЕСТЬ, но перечисление относится к слову ВСЁ) следует склонять.
2. Суффикса ЮЖ не существует.

Comment: В слове денюжка "юж" - часть корня. Примеры корней с "юж": утюж+ок, дерюж+ка, верблюж+онок